# Android: Send a touch event

Tags: android, touch

In Android is it possible to send touch events to the screen? I want to programmatically toggle a button from a third party app by sending a touch event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible using one of these two approaches:

- Root your device

  - Direct injection to /dev/input/eventX
  - Using InputManager.injectTouchEvent()
  - Using WindowManager.injectPointerEvent()
- Create an `AccessibilityService`. Notice that this is not guaranteed to work with all third-party apps.

Comment: Hi! I see you know a lot about touch events. I'm trying to send a touch event (press the upper left corner of the screen), but I don't know Java at all, and I can't get it to work. I have tried this code, as a Java scriptlet using Tasker (which has root access), but I have no idea what it means, and I'm probably doing something wrong, or I may need some preperatory line of code first: `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100, 100, 0));` Of course if you have no time, I understand.